# Can't I play PS4 without paying PS Plus?

Tags: ps4, playstation-plus

I don't know much about game consoles.

I recently bought a PS4 with the sole purpose of playing a multiplayer/networking game with two other people, that's it.

Do I really need to pay a monthly rate to play with them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is yes.

And the long answer is yesssssssssss.

But more seriously, you will need a Playstation Network Subscription to play online with your friends. You can play local multiplayer without a subscription, but if you want to go online against the greater community, you'll need to pay the monthly/yearly fee.

Comment: How can I play local multiplayer without a subscription? Can we be in different locations? I have no interest in going online against the greater community.

Comment: Local is just that you and your friends will need to play on the same console.

Comment: No, you need to all be in the same room. Split screen largely depends on the game in question.

Comment: The only reason I bought the PS4 is because these two other people want to play. Otherwise, I wouldn't have spent the money in the console.

Comment: Understood, so anything that uses the internet will require a Playstation Network Subscription?

Comment: That is correct. If you want to play Online against the greater PSN community, you will need a PSN subscription.

Comment: Anything that requires a synchronous server presence requires PS Plus. There are games that feature online mode of play which are also considered part of the greater player community that do not require PS Plus (Let it Die, Bloodborne, PlanetSide 2, etc.) If you and your friends are going to primarily play FPS and MMO games, then Kaizerwolf is correct.

Answer (score 1):

For what I believe you're asking to do - **yes** the *general* idea regarding online play with friends (depending on game) is subscription based and is slowly becoming the staple in console gaming but not all online features and online game modes require PS Plus.

For example, *Let it Die* is played online without PS Plus subscription  and *Bloodborne* has aspects of online play that do not require a PS Plus subscription.

Note that the PSN subscription works two primary ways and a third way that Sony has mainly let external forces control thus far.

In 2013, PlayStationLifestyle.net [wrote a blurb](https://www.google.com/amp/www.playstationlifestyle.net/2013/06/12/new-ps-ps4-online-requirement-info-asynchronous-online-gameplay-f2p-games-like-planetside-2-are-free-play-without-plus/amp/?client=ms-android-americamovil-us) regarding the following facts:

For what you're looking to do, Sony calls "*synchronous play*" or play where both devices have to be in synch to enjoy (Call of Duty, for example).

However, "*asynchronous play*" (turn based online games, for example) and F2P (free to play) games do not require a PSN account to play online.

Additionally MMO (Massively Multi-Player Online) titles (like Final Fantasy XIV) are decided upon by the developer / publisher.

These rules only apply to the PS4 as of right now and PS Plus is a growing requirement for online gaming.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for most of the game you'll need it.

Some free game don't require it tough, the few I know are *War Thunder, BlackLight and Smite.*